# How do I make 'continue' statement iterate the "mother" loop outside of loop where the statement is found? (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

So I have a code in this format:

```
for-loop1:
    for-loop2:
        if-statement:
            continue
        <code here>
        <code there>
```

The question is, how do I make the continue statement iterate for-loop1 and not just for-loop2? Putting the statement in line with the for-loop2 line would iterat for-loop1 without even executing the rest of the code first. Help :(

Answer (score 1):

If there's no code after `for-loop2`, a `break` will effectively restart the outer loop.

```
for-loop1:
    for-loop2:
        if-statement:
            break
        <code here>
        <code there>
```

If there is additional stuff after the inner loop then it'll take a bit more doing.

```
for-loop1:
    restart_loop1 = False

    for-loop2:
        if-statement:
            restart_loop1 = True
            break

        <code here>
        <code there>

    if restart_loop1:
        continue

    <more code here>
```

Comment: Will this terminate the program or will this only terminate for-loop2? I'm doing a program with file handling and it's hard to track because i'm not getting all correct outputs as of the moment. :/

Comment: Try to understand the code. This will terminate the inner loop.